# Including JavaScript class definition from another file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a simple server for Node.js and I'm using my own class called `User` which looks like:

```
function User(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.nickname = null;

    /* ... just the typical source code like functions, variables and bugs ... */

    this.write = function(object) {
        this.socket.write(JSON.stringify(object));
    }
};
```

and then later in the process I'm instantiating it a lot:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    /* other bugs */
    var user = new User(socket);
    /* more bugs and bad practise */
});
```

Can I move my `User` class definition to another javascript file and "include" it somehow?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You can simply do this:

**user.js**

```js
class User {
  //...
}

module.exports = User //  Export class
```

**server.js**

```js
const User = require('./user.js')

let user = new User()
```

This is called [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) module.

### ES Modules

Since Node.js version 14 it's possible to use ES Modules with CommonJS. Read more about it in the [ESM documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html).

**user.mjs** ( extension is important)

```js
export default class User {}
```

**server.mjs**

```js
import User from './user.mjs'

let user = new User()
```

Comment: what if, User had some input parameters, like module.exports = function User(data). Then the var user = new User(); whould have been changed to var user = new User(data);?

Comment: Yes. `User` is usual js function.

Comment: You don't need to create the constant User in server.js. Change the last line of users.js into `module.exports = new User();`
This will create a new instance of User each time the module is required. Then you can simply require the module for each variable like this: `let user = require('./user.js');`.

Comment: This is incorrect. It will create user instance just once when module is required.

Comment: @Pasha Rumkin what you say is wrong. This answer is correct.

Comment: @Barnack There are several my answers. Which is wrong and which is correct?

Comment: @pashaRumkin Instantiate object locally, but I got TypeError: <ClassName> is not a constructor

Comment: @MdAlamin It's better to create a new question with complete source code to anyone could help you. Anyway could not say something without your code source.

Answer (score 16):

Using ES6, you can have `user.js`:

```
export default class User {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then use it in `server.js`

```
const User = require('./user.js').default;
const user = new User();
```

Comment: i get an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` when i do as you described... i have node version `v10.16.3`

Answer (score 7):

Modify your class definition to read like this:

```
exports.User = function (socket) {
  ...
};
```

Then rename the file to `user.js`. Assuming it's in the root directory of your main script, you can include it like this:

```
var user = require('./user');
var someUser = new user.User();
```

That's the quick and dirty version. Read about [CommonJS Modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: What happened to socket? should it be var someUser = new user.User(socket);

Answer (score 5):

Another way in addition to the ones provided here for ES6

```
module.exports = class TEST{
    constructor(size) {
        this.map = new MAp();
        this.size = size;

    }

    get(key) {
        return this.map.get(key);
    }

    length() {
        return this.map.size;
    }    

}
```

and include the same as

```
var TEST= require('./TEST');
var test = new TEST(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you append this to `user.js`:

```
exports.User = User;
```

then in `server.js` you can do:

```
var userFile = require('./user.js');
var User = userFile.User;
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/globals.html#require

Another way is:

```
global.User = User;
```

then this would be enough in `server.js`:

```
require('./user.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Paul Rumkin answer(the first answer), you can use the ES Modules class with the `.js` extension and **don't have to use the`.mjs` extension**.

To do that, make sure you have the `package.json` file. If you don't have one, run the following command to create it:

```
npm init -y
```

Add `"type": "module"` at the end of your the `package.json` file:

```
{
 ...
 "type": "module" 
}
```

Create **user.js** file  and export a class from it:

```
export default class User {}
```

Import the class in **server.js**:

```
import User from './user.js'

let user = new User()
```