# What is the correct way to split firebase cloud functions into different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to split a large cloud function into a smaller more maintainable files. However when deploying I always get the same error:

```
Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/Raphi/Documents/Programing/Development/merchantAPI/functions/index.js:2
import { DirectPost } from '../functions/merchantPost';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I spent most of last night googling but there doesn't seem to be any documentation for this

simplified index.js:

```
import { DirectPost } from '../functions/merchantPost';
exports.portal = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  var charge = new DirectPost()
})
```

simplified merchantPost.js:

```
export class DirectPost {
  constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: awesome, that worked add answer so i can mark as correct please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Including JavaScript class definition from another file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6998355/6002078).

Also consider making a separate file for the "portal handler" callback, so that you can do

```
exports.portal = functions.https.onRequest(portalHandler);
```

It makes your index.js much cleaner.

Also consider using TypeScript (in which importing stuff is done exactly as you're trying to in your code) which will help you in the long run by preventing some nasty bugs...