# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module firebase deploy error using typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

When I attempt to `firebase deploy` I get the following error.

It seems to be about this line: `import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';`  at the begining of my file. I have not had any issues with this in the past. But I have recently [been having issues with NPM and deploying](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firestore-codelab-extended-swift/issues/45).

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/name/Desktop/Yoveo/functions/src/index.ts:1
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1052:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:27)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1281:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1024:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1225:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at /Users/name/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
name@name-MacBook-Pro functions %
```

**How can I fix it?**

I ran npm update and then ran firebase deploy again. got the same error. But with a recommendation to run npm install -g firebase-tools which after running deploy again, resulted in no change for the error.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you did to get to this point.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've had this issue for months. I don't think I will be able to recreate it. I will see what I can do.

Comment: I was unable to recreate. If anyone has suggestions that would be helpful.

Comment: We need at least a part of your code. Also check the similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761839/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-firebase-functions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871924/what-is-the-correct-way-to-split-firebase-cloud-functions-into-different-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I searched `AsyncIterable` in my folder. It returned a bunch of associated files connected to the different projects I have. I then highlighted and looked at the file path for all of them.

I found that the ones working correctly where associated with a project, and that the project that was not working would not show up. Except, however, for some files associated with no Xcode project.

Thus I concluded that there may have been a problem with the initial setup where many necessary files were associated with no particular project. Dont know how that happened. I will work to solve that now. Comment if you know how I could redo this or fix this issue.