# NodeJS export class cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently trying to add a service layer to my NodeJS project, which is a simple API I build using express and sequelize. The project has a structure of the usual model, route, and controller (MRC) form; each has its own directory. Now all I need to do is add another directory that will contain the service files. The files will contain the business logic in the form of a class that I will export and include in my controller files.

Here I will display the controller and service files:

**eruptionController.js**

```
const EruptionService = require('../services/eruptionService.js');
let Eruption = new EruptionService()


module.exports = {
    getEruptions: (req, res) => {
        Eruption.get().then(result => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: "Get All Eruptions",
                result
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: "internal Server Error",
                error: err.message
            })
        })
    }
};
```

**eruptionService.js**

```
const { eruption } = require('../models');

class EruptionService {
    constructor () {
        this.eruptionModel = eruption;
        
    }

    get () {
        this.eruptionModel.findAll()
        .then(result => result)
        .catch(err => err)
    }
}

module.exports = EruptionService;
```

As we can see here, in the service file, I imported the `eruption` model from the model folder and include it in the constructor. Then I created a method named `get`, which purpose to retrieve all the eruption data from the database.

After that, I imported the `EruptionService` class into the controller file, initiated it as an instance, and include the class in the `getEruptions` function. The function will then be used in an express route in the form of an endpoint.

**The issue** is that when I tried to send a request to the endpoint, I got the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Based on the error, it seems that the `EruptionService` class was not exported properly since when I called the mothed `get` it's undefined.

I've been stuck with this for a while now, and I'm not really sure what's going on. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998355/including-javascript-class-definition-from-another-file-in-node-js), I seem to be exporting the class properly.

I've also tried exporting in a way like below

```
module.exports = {EruptionService: EruptionService}
```

And I've also tried importing like

```
const EruptionService = require('../services/eruptionService.js');
```

But in the end, it either results in the same error or different one kind of error. I was wondering if anybody could point out what I was missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `get()` method doesn't `return` the promise. There's no problem with the exports - if there was, you'd get something like "*`EruptionService` is not a constructor*".

Comment: Btw, [drop the pointless `.then(result => result)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572) and avoid using `catch` when you cannot actually handle the error (eg. by returing an empty list as a fallback).

Comment: @Bergi okay noted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a promise function for getting the then function inside it. There is a issue in your service it should be like the below snippet

```
 class EruptionService {
    constructor () {
        this.eruptionModel = eruption;
        
    }

    get () {
        return this.eruptionModel.findAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: now the get function is returning a promise function and it can used like a promise or can also be used as async/await function.